# Problema al refrescar web con JQuery y Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy haciendo que una parte de mi web se actualice "automáticamente" con ayuda de jquery, el problema, es que la sección que estoy actualizando es un archivo JS, que dentro tiene un `innerHTML`, y al cargar el script para que se actualice, ya no lo toma como un innerHTML y lo toma como un texto plano.

**index.html:**

```
<script src="html.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        setInterval(
                function(){
                    $('#demo2').load('html.js');
                },200
            );
     });

</script>
```

**html.js:**

```
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "<h1>Este texto se actualiza solo</h5>";
```

Las etiquetas dentro del innerHTML las respeta, pero el texto ("`document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML`") también lo imprime, como si fuera HTML.

Alguien me podría ayudar (Que no copie un codigo que no tenga nada que ver con la pregunta)

REVIVO

Answer (score 1):

La función .load() retorna texto de un archivo.
Hay otra función llamada .getScript(), que retorna, lee y ejecuta codigo Javascript

```js
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML =
  "<h1>Este texto se actualiza solo</h5>";
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $.getScript("app.js", function (data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
          console.log(data); // Data returned
          console.log(textStatus); // Success
          console.log(jqxhr.status); // 200
          console.log("Load was performed.");
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="demo2"><h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2></div>

    <button>Get External Content</button>
    <script></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Te dejo la documentación y espero que te sirva.
[jquery getScript()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/)

Comment: Si, y ahora como hago para que se actualice cada 2 segundos o 2000 milisegundos?

Comment: @MatiST00 busca esta función setInterval

Comment: Gracias, pero creo que no me sirve así entonces.

Comment: @MatiST00 esa función que te digo cumple con lo que quieres hacer Ya se te ayudo con el post ahora investiga bro

Comment: Gracias @Alex, pero no me ha ayudado mucho, porque pregunto X y me respondes Z, pero gracias igualmente.

Comment: O está incompleta, y sin una guía para ayudar. Todo explicado en el aire, sin un link.

Comment: @MatiST00 https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval

Comment: Te agradezco, pero se está alargando el hilo. Y vas respondiendo por partes, sin ayudar, te recomiendo que leas la guia de como responder. O edita la respuesta.

Comment: Esto es una respuesta copiada de otro sitio, eso no está permitido en el sitio.

Answer (score 1):

La función load de Jquery sirve para cargar en un DIV un archivo externo, ya sea un php, un asp... etc.
El caso es que al hacer load, lo que carga en dentro del DIV es el contenido del js, por lo cual al pasar el tiempo que estableces, quedaría el código del html así:

```
<div id="demo2">document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "<h1>Este texto se actualiza solo</h5>";</div>
```

No interpreta el código ya que no está metido entre  y por lo tanto se muestra el código como si fuera html.

Por otro lado, la etiqueta h1 esta cerrada con una /h5.

Espero haberte ayudado.
Un saludo!

Comment: Y se puede hacer algo para que funcione?

Comment: @MatiST00 Prueba la segunda respuesta, con ese código si funciona.